# Unscope specific where values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have Product model with many tags

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end
```

I apply multiple where conditions to Product scope

```
@products = Product.includes(:tags).where(tags: { id: [1] })
@products = @products.where(tags: { id: [2] })
```

Later in code I need to unscope @products relation. But only specific condition group, and not whole where clause.

```
@products = @products.somehow_i_dont_know_how_unscope(tags: { id: [2] })

assert_eqal Product.includes(:tags).where(tags: { id: [1] }), @products
```

According to business logic I cant do this check before actually applying where condition. Is there any way to revert such condition later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my idea that we remove the specific `where` from the [where_clause](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/where_clause.rb), `rewhere`, `unscope` also do that way.

```rb
@products = Product.includes(:tags).where(tags: { id: [1] })
@products = @products.where(tags: { id: [2] })

@products.where_clause -= Product.where(tags: { id: [2] }).where_clause

assert_equal Product.includes(:tags).where(tags: { id: [1] }), @products # ok
```

Comment: @Lam Phan I've got you idea. It works, but only if scope argument to -= exactly matches original array.  [2,9999] - and this is skipped instead of removing only "2" clause